# ES6 TemplateUrl like Angular2

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking into ES6 and found Template strings which I like.

With ES6 Template Strings I am able to inject html like this:

```
$("#warning").html(`
      <h1>Watch out!</h1>
      <p>Unauthorized hockeying can result in penalties of up to 500 minutes.</p>
`);
```

Backticks are a really useful feature of ES6.

In AngularJs2 you can use TemplateUrl and actually import an external page.

Can this be done with ES6 (without Angular2), if so how?

Comment: This is in ES6 already? https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-template-strings-in-depth

Comment: Oh, and to use ES6 without using Angular2, you need a transpiler like Babel or Traceur. For ex Node, using babel-cli you can run `babel-node es6script.js` and you can use template strings

Comment: I've been about the use ES6 without it on my browser. Mix of jQuery and ES6: <script>

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#warning").html(`
    <h1>Watch out!</h1>
    <p>Unauthorized hockeying can result in penalties of up to 500 minutes.</p>
  `);

 });

</script>  .. It works fine

Comment: This links shows ES6 browser support https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Yeah, I'm experimenting with FF, which has good support ... But I'd like to know it templateUrl exists as I cannot find it

Comment: Sorry for not reading your question right! I think you need to use an AMD for that, like SystemJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is already ES6 but it won't always work because template strings take into account *all* whitespace, including the whitespace you use to indent your code for clarity.

You have a couple options.

Use string concatenation:

```js
$("#warning").html(
  `<h1>Watch out!</h1>` +
  `<p>Unauthorized hockeying can result in penalties of up to 500 minutes.</p>`
);
```

My preferred method is array joining:

```js
$("#warning").html([
  `<h1>Watch out!</h1>`,
  `<p>Unauthorized hockeying can result in penalties of up to 500 minutes.</p>`
].join(''));
```